# java query not passing test case

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

This is the question:

> A DoSoD number is a Divisor of Sum of Digits. For example, if you take
>   the number 12, its sum of digits is 1 + 2 = 3. 12 is divisible by 3
>   and hence it is a DoSoD number. By the same reasoning, 11 is not a
>   DoSoD number, but the closest DoSoD number to 11 is 12. Write a
>   program that will take an integer n as input and print the DoSoD
>   number closest to but not less than n. Sample input-1 16 Expected
>   output 18 Sample input-2 20 Expected output 20

This is my code:

```
class Dosod{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int temp=0,x;
        x=n;
        int y=n;
        while(n>0){
            x=n%10;
            temp+=x;
            n=n/10;
        }
        if(y%temp==0){
             System.out.print(y);
        }else if(y%temp!=0){
           y=y+2;
            System.out.println(y);
        }


    }
}
```

But its is not passing the test case .Can anybody help ?

Comment: May you attach your test case please?

Comment: I don't know ! what are test cases

Comment: They are given in question itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your else branch. Your closest number could be forward or backward from current number. But since problem statement explicitly says closest value should be greater than input value. You can write a simple while loop which increments input value till value mod `sumOfDigits` is 0.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int y = n;
        int temp = 0;       
        temp = sumOfDigits(n);

        if (y % temp == 0) {
            System.out.print(y);
        } 
        else
        {
            int yforward = y+1;

            while(yforward % sumOfDigits(yforward) !=0)
                yforward++;

            System.out.println(yforward);
        }


    }

    static int sumOfDigits(int n)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            int x = n % 10;
            temp += x;
            n = n / 10;
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Inan mentioned you need to **update** your else branch, but you could also improve your flow control with just a while `statement`, it's pretty much clear and definitely more elegant. also added another way to sum digits to your study case. plus, it is nice if you "ask" for input when needed, so the user can see what is going on. And last but not less important (i'm sorry if i'm being too strict) it's a good practice if your variables name are representative, this way are more readable for programmers. i.e. `int inputNumber = s.nextInt();`.

---

### Dosod:

```
class Dosod{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print ( "Please enter a number: " );
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int inputNumber = s.nextInt();        
        
        while ( inputNumber % sumOfDigits ( inputNumber ) != 0 )
        {
            inputNumber++;
        }
        System.out.println ( "dosod: " + inputNumber );

    }

    static int sumOfDigits(int number)
    {
        String digits = new Integer(number).toString();
        int sum = 0;
        for (char c: digits.toCharArray())
            sum += c - '0';
        return sum;
    }
}
```

---

### Input/Outputs examples:

```
Please enter a number: 19
Dosod: 20
Please enter a number: 12
Dosod: 12
Please enter a number: 37
Dosod: 40
```

---

### Workflow:

If you still have any doubts, check this workflow:

[image: workflow]

---

### Docs:

[Naming Conventions (archived)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

[Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)